# Evaluating a function after simplifying to avoid infinite expressions

Tags: simplifying-expressions, evaluation

[image: Question]

My Poly[j_, s_] function simplifies to a polynomial for all j. So I defined a PolySim[j_, s_] = Simplify[Poly[j,s]] function.

However, if I try to evaluate PolySim[j,0], since this is PolySim[j,0] = Simplify[Poly[j,0]] and it plugs in s = 0 before simplifying it to a polynomial, leading to infinite expression and messes up my calculation.

Is there any way I can simplify first and then evaluate with my desired values?

Thanks!

Comment: `PolySim[3, s] /. s -> 0`

Comment: @MariusLadegårdMeyer Ah, Thanks so much! I'm trying to plot PolySim for s between 0 and 1; in that case how should I specify the range? {s,0,1} doesn't work for obvious reasons :(

Comment: Redefine `PolySim` like so: `PolySim[j_, s_] := Block[{x}, Simplify[Poly[j, x]] /. x -> s]`

Comment: @MariusLadegårdMeyer Mhm worked like a charm; thank you so much!!!

Comment: I wouldn't  use Simplify in a SetDelayed (:=) definition if you are going to use  it in a plot, as this will cause it to be evaluated for every single point in the plot. Slow!

Comment: Please do not post images of your work. Please post your actual _Mathematica_ code in the form of text that can be copied and pasted into a _Mathematica_ notebook. Without such, it will be difficult to reproduce your problem and to experiment with possible repairs.

Comment: I really wish you'd given a copyable version of your code, as m_goldberg says; I have a few ideas, but I'll be damned if I have to retype all that...

Answer (score 2):

In general to avoid divergences you can use the Limit function.
Example, let be

```
num[x_, n_, j_] := (1/(x - j))Product[x - i, {i, 1, n}]
```

Then

```
num[x, 6, 3]
```

produces $(-6 + x) (-5 + x) (-4 + x) (-2 + x) (-1 + x)$. If I want to evaluate this function when $x=3$, it's "obvious" that it will be $(-6 + 3) (-5 + 3) (-4 + 3) (-2 + 3) (-1 + 3)=-12$, but if I write it like this

```
num[3, 6, 3]
```

Mathematica gives me

```
"Infinite expression 1/0 encountered."
```

To avoid this divergence I can use the Limit function as follows:

```
Limit[num[x, 6, 3], x -> 3]
```

which returns $-12$, as expected.